# Pandas dataframe get columns names and value_counts

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

how to get all column names where values in columns are 'f' or 't' into array ?

```
df['FTI'].value_counts()
```

instead of this 'FTI' i need array of returned columns. Is it possible?

Comment: Please post an example data frame.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/l5rrms i want get column names 3,4,5,6 into array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':[1,2,3], 'col2':['f', 'f', 'f'], 'col3': ['t','t','t'], 'col4':['d','d','d']})

    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   1       f       t       d
1   2       f       t       d
2   3       f       t       d
```

Such that, using [`eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and [`all`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
>>> s = (df.eq('t') | df.eq('f')).all()

col1    False
col2     True
col3     True
col4    False
dtype: bool
```

To get the names:

```
>>> s[s].index.values
array(['col2', 'col3'], dtype=object)
```

To get the positions:

```
>>> np.flatnonzero(s) + 1
array([2, 3])
```

Comment: i have every column as False, so there must be something what i dont see.. but now i know how to do it, thank you

Comment: @efysis If you want to check if there is *at least one* `f` or `t`, you can use `.any()` instead of `.all()`. The latter will check if every single cell in that column is `f` or `t` ;)

Comment: that is exactly what i wanted!, problem with all() was that in some rows are null values, i guess

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is possible. Here is one way

You can get the columns like this.

```
cols=[]
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].str.contains('f|t').any()==True:
        cols.append(col)
```

Then you can just use this for frequencies

```
f= pd.Series()
for col in cols:
    f=pd.concat([f,df[col].value_counts()])
```